# Git merge different repositories which are basically the same

Tags: git, merge, patch, rebase

## Problem

I have two different repositories which are basically the same. Lets name one `RepoA` and the other `RepoB`.

`RepoA` is the *first* repository which has the following structure:

- `FolderA`

  - `2018`
- `FolderB`

  - `2018`

`RepoB` is the *second* repository. The first commit contains all files of the last commit of `RepoB`. Therefore the first commit is basically a copy, but it contains the following structure:

- `FolderA`

  - `2019`
- `FolderB`

  - `2019`

So all the content from `RepoA/FolderA/2018/` is now in `RepoB/FolderA/2019/` plus some new changes which are commited in `RepoB`.

### Goal

I came new into the project and want to merge both of the repositories to have access to the history of the file (`git log` and so on).

I want the following structure:

- `FolderA`
- `FolderB`

## Approach

1. In `RepoA` I moved all files from `FolderA/2018` to `FolderA` and deleted `FolderA` (*same for `FolderB`*)
2. I cherry picked the initial commit from `RepoB` into `RepoA` and moved the files on directory up (as described in the previous point)
3. I extracted the following commits in `RepoB` as patch and modified all paths with search and replace
4. I applied the patch via `git am < patchfile`

### Problem

Because of the patch the branches are removed and the history becomes linear. Therefore I run into problems when there is a commit followed by a merge which resolves a merge conflict which is introduced by the commit.

Comment: Have you tried with `git rebase --preserve-merges`? I think it'll try to recreate the history with all the branching. And I think it will find the renamed files and apply the changes to the right files.

Comment: I gave up. I have the feeling that this works somehow but with a lot of manual work.

Comment: Can't you just `fetch` the other repo and then `merge`? Maybe perform a subtree merge or move/rename files in both repos before merging.